# Fortify thinks there's log forging on a strongly typed object, unless I manually call .toString()

Tags: java, fortify

I have a page token object which is a wrapper around a Long, with a static String inside it to have the namespace. In my application, we're using Spring @PathVariable to have Jackson build these objects, and then we're logging the page token on failures. Fortify thinks that this is potential log forging, but there's really no chance of that, since our toString() method is just: `return PREFIX + StringUtils.leftPad(Long.toString(value), 7, '0')`.

I've tried two ways to make Fortify happy with this, and neither was a good fit.
I could add a SuppressionRule:

```
    <SuppressionRule formatVersion="17.20">
        <RuleID>94236098-4C10-41F0-9C2A-27A3919830000</RuleID>
    </SuppressionRule>
```

However, that would also make it not find actual log forging from @PathVariable Strings.

I tried adding a DataflowCleanseRule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RulePack xmlns="xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/rules">
    <RulePackID>55290199-F943-4BF1-9DCE-A3E28DD1342A</RulePackID>
    <SKU>SKU-cleanse</SKU>
    <Name><![CDATA[cleanse]]></Name>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <Description><![CDATA[Tell Fortify that Page Identifiers can't cause log forging.]]></Description>
    <Rules version="17.20">
        <RuleDefinitions>
            <DataflowCleanseRule formatVersion="17.20" language="java">
                <RuleID>DDAB5D73-8CF6-45E0-888C-EEEFBEFF2CD5</RuleID>
                <TaintFlags>+VALIDATED_LOG_FORGING</TaintFlags>
                <FunctionIdentifier>
                    <NamespaceName>
                        <Pattern>page\.id\.</Pattern>
                    </NamespaceName>
                    <ClassName>
                        <Pattern>Id</Pattern>
                    </ClassName>
                    <FunctionName>
                        <Pattern>toString</Pattern>
                    </FunctionName>
                    <ApplyTo implements="true" overrides="true" extends="true"/>
                </FunctionIdentifier>
                <OutArguments>return</OutArguments>
            </DataflowCleanseRule>
        </RuleDefinitions>
    </Rules>
</RulePack>
```

But it didn't stop the log forging warnings. The IDs are classes like `page.id.v1.NewsId`.

Additionally, if I put a `newsId.toString()` anywhere in my package at all, it realizes that all of them are safe, and my warnings all go away. Is this a bug in Fortify, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@andersonshatch started me on the right path, realizing that I needed to convince Fortify that it was safe no matter what, whenever one of these objects was seen. The file that ended up working for me is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RulePack xmlns="xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/rules">
    <RulePackID>55290199-F943-4BF1-9DCE-A3E28DD1342A</RulePackID>
    <SKU>SKU-cleanse</SKU>
    <Name><![CDATA[cleanse]]></Name>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <Description><![CDATA[Tell Fortify that Page Identifiers can't cause XSS or log forging.]]></Description>
    <Rules version="17.20">
        <RuleDefinitions>
            <CharacterizationRule formatVersion="17.20" language="java">
                <RuleID>34711D7A-C2BC-40B3-B1DE-B5C48EF65646</RuleID>
                <StructuralMatch><![CDATA[VariableAccess va: va.type.name matches "page.id.*"]]>
                </StructuralMatch>
                <Definition><![CDATA[TaintCleanse(va)]]></Definition>
            </CharacterizationRule>
        </RuleDefinitions>
    </Rules>
</RulePack>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FunctionIdentifier` value in your cleanse rule should refer to the fully qualified package, class and function name of the function that generates the identifier for this case, rather than the string you use to get the identifier in your jsp/template etc.,

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish that, since these are being created by Spring and passed in to Controllers.

Comment: And putting a DataflowCleanseRule (outargument=this) or DataflowEntryPointRule(inargument = 0) on the constructor doesn't appear to do anything either. 

The Spring rule I'm violating to set this all off is:
    `Rule ID: 94236098-4C10-41F0-9C2A-27A3919830000
    createModelAndView(0)
    Spring Entry Point`

Comment: I've also tried a CharacterizationRule: 
`<StructuralMatch><![CDATA[  VariableAccess va: va.type.name matches "page.id.*"   ]]>  </StructuralMatch>  <Definition><![CDATA[                     TaintEntrypoint(va, {+VALIDATED_XSS +VALIDATED_WEB +VALIDATED_LOG_FORGING})        ]]></Definition> `
 but that didn't help either.